# Django Annotate and Aggregate

Tags: django-models, django-annotate, django-aggregation

I'd like to Sum the post_value of all of the Posts for each post_user to eventually use in a chart. I'm struggling with how to formulate the query?

So far, I've got to:

```
user_totals = User.objects.annotate(post_value_total=Sum('post'))
```

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Post(models.Model):
    post_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_cat = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_action = models.ForeignKey(Action, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    post_value = models.PositiveIntegerField(default='0')
    post_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.post_user}'s post at {self.post_timestamp}"
```

Thanks.

Comment: So you want the total number of `Post`s? Since each `Post` has a non-NULL field that refers to a `post_user`, the total number of `Post`s for all users, is the number of `Post`s in total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to Sum the post_value of all of the Posts for each post_user to eventually use in a chart.

Since each `Post` has a non-nullable `post_user` `ForeignKey`, it means that each `Post` belongs to *exactly* one user.

We thus can sum up the number of `post_value`s of all `User`s with:

```
Post.objects.all().count()
```

If you only want to sum these up for a subset of the users, you can work with:

```
Post.objects.filter(
    post_user__in=[user1, user2, user3]
).count()
```

or if you have ids:

```
Post.objects.filter(
    post_user_id__in=[user_id1, user_id2, user_id3]
).count()
```

Or if you want to sum up the `post_value`s, you can work with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

total_post_value = Post.objects.aggregate(
    total=Sum('post_value')
) or 0
```

The `or 0` is necessary if the collection can be empty, since the sum of no records is `NULL`/`None`, not `0`.

Or if you want to do this *per* `User`, we can work with:

```
user_totals = User.objects.annotate(
    post_value_total=Sum('post__post_value')
)
```

The `User` objects that arise from this will have an extra attribute `post_value_total` that sums up the values of the *related* `Post`s. These can be `None` if a user has no related `Post`s. In that case we can work [**`Coalesce`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce):

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

user_totals = User.objects.annotate(
    post_value_total=Coalesce(Sum('post__post_value'), Value(0))
)
```

Comment: Thanks Willem, but I am trying to Sum the post_value of all of the Posts that each User has recorded, not the number of Posts for each User?

Comment: @EwanWillsmer: by using count, we *aggregate*, so we will count the total number of posts submitted by *all* users (code fragment 1), or if we want to do that for a specific group for users (fragments 2 and 3). These will thus all return a *scalar* integer.

Comment: post_value is a field in the Post model. I am not interested in the number of Posts, I am interested in the total post_value for all of the Posts related to each User.

Comment: @EwanWillsmer: then you thus simply want to sum up the `post_value`s for each `Post`? Since each `Post` relates to exactly *one* it does not matter to first annotate.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but I would like to get a total_post_value for each User. The total_post_value would be the sum of the post_value from each of their Posts.

Comment: @EwanWillsmer: see edit to calculate this *per* `User`.